# How to get value of input type file as name was array?

Tags: laravel-5

I am having problem of getting value from input file from my html. The name of the input file is an array. It's work fine if I want to get value of the input file just the normal name.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="collateral_photo[]" id="collateral_photo" class="default" />
```

**PHP:**

> $file = Request::file('collateral_photo');
>
> return $file;

The value return is empty.
What I want is to get value from input file as array.
Please tell how to do that. I'm newbie to Laravel 5.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = Input::file('collateral_photo');
```

Have you done this (`multipart/form-data`):

```
<form ..... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Yes, I do have it in my form.